# Debussy's 'sneaky Tristan' in his own performance of 'Golliwogg's Cakewalk'?

Tags: chords

I don't understand [this comment under the piano ROLL recording on Youtube :](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMrdhgWR9Zk&google_comment_id=z124wl4adrq1jfjrd04cchfpjlffjtgj4ec)

> User [Henry Baxter]:
>
> ***Sneaky*** bit of **tristan** at 1:10﻿

Am I right that '**tristan**' refers to the [Tristan chord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tristan_chord)?
Even if so, what's ***sneaky*** in Debussy's performance?

Answer (score 5):

It's a little sneakier than that. Here's the [score](http://javanese.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/3/3a/IMSLP93799-PMLP02387-Debussy_golliwoggs_cakewalk__Transc_2011-RSB_.pdf); look for yourself. The passage in question starts at m. 61. Debussy quotes the melody *at pitch* of the opening measure-and-a-half of the Prelude to Tristan, but he never quite lands on the Tristan chord - there's always something a little off. He repeats it several times, landing a couple of times each on A♭ minor with added fourth and a minor seventh chord on E♭ (plus a few more, none of which is the Tristan chord) before dissolving the quotation into cakewalk figuration.